# Marshalling setup when using obj-c class in nativescript (with typescript) project

Tags: objective-c, typescript, nativescript, metadata, marshalling

Following the instructions on https://nativescript.org/blog/adding-objective-c-code-to-a-nativescript-app/ I setup a very simple nativescript project (with typescript underneath):

1. tns create simpleApp --tsc
2. tns platform add ios
3. tns prepare ios
4. run the generated ios project via xcode.

The app runs correctly.

Next I added a custom obj-c class to the project (App_Resources/iOS/src/Stuff .h and .m):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Stuff: NSObject
+(void)doStuff;
@end
```

```
#import "Stuff.h"

@implementation Stuff
+(void)doStuff {
    NSLog(@"I should see this...");
}
@end
```

And a module.modulemap:

```
module Stuff {
    header "Stuff.h"
    export *
}
```

A `tns prapare ios` command successfully processes the class.

When I try to add the 'Stuff' object to the typescript source, I get a `cannot find name Stuff`.
How do I get the marshalling/metadata between typescript and obj-c working? Do I need to run some scripts? add imports? The tutorial does not mention anything about that...

This is what I added to the nativescript default template app:

```
onTap() {
        this._counter--;
        this.updateMessage();
        Stuff.doStuff();
    }
```

And hoped to see the log text when tapping the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add the required .d.ts files to the project:
[generating-typescript-typings](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/use-native-ios-libraries#generating-typescript-typings)

Run the following in the src-root of your nativescript project:

```
TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/typings" tns build ios
```

It generates a typings folder containing all the .d.ts files for the ios classes, including the Stuff class that was created manually. The Typescript code is correctly being interpreted now... New obj-c classes can be addressed in the TS code once they have been processed by the line above.